My Customize Bootstrap 5.3 - Problem Login Page NOT Center
I want to use customized Bootstrap 5.3 for my project using the  saas files. .
Reason for use , I want to minimize Size of Bootstrap.
After compile using 'source.scss' , I found customized  saas files Bootstrap,
make mine login Page NOT Center.
What missing "import" file bootstrap that I not include below ? Pls help
(source.scss) file:
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_maps.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_mixins.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_root.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_utilities.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_reboot.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_type.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_images.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_containers.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_grid.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_tables.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_forms.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_buttons.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_dropdown.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_button-group.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_nav.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_navbar.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_card.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_breadcrumb.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_pagination.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_badge.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_alert.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_progress.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_list-group.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_close.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_modal.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_spinners.scss";

#Bootstrap #Bootstrap5.3
Help the missing saas files. How make the login page in center as per image
Login_Page
